# Optimal method for executing a $resource call from a <select> when using the keyboard

Tags: javascript, angularjs

## Use Case

Using a drop-down menu to control resource selection can be useful, but may trigger many `$resource` calls during the on change event. Adding in a `ng-model-options: { debounce: 1000}` will provide a much more optimized solution. However, the following problems exist when **using the keyboard down button** to control the `<select>`.

1. If the model defaults to null, users can only select between the null option and first option.
2. Once the first option is selected, the user can only select between the first and second option.
3. After the second option is select, normal behaviour returns and the user can scroll down the list.

Oddly, using the **up button** has no problems.

## Questions

1. Is there a way to fix this behaviour or
2. Is there a better way to trigger the `$resource` call only when the user stops selecting an option from the drop-down?

### Environment

- Google Chrome
- AngularJS v1.3.0-beta.14

### Code

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MrRampage/BV6v4/)

#### HTML

```
<select ng-model="item" 
    autofocus
    ng-options="item as item.name for item in items"
    ng-model-options="{debounce: 1000}"
    ng-change="test()">
</select>
```

#### Controller

```
function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.item = null;
    $scope.items = [ 
        { name: 'duck' }, 
        { name: 'cow'}, 
        { name: 'poodle'} ];

    $scope.test = function() {
        // Resource call to service
        console.log("Changed!");
    };

    // initialize the array
    function ctor() {
        var randNames = [...];
        angular.forEach(randNames, function(item) {
            $scope.items.push({ name: item });
        });
    };

    ctor();
};
```

Comment: Is using `ng-blur` instead of `ng-change` an option?  That would call the function only when the select box loses focus.

Comment: demo works fine for me in chrome and firefox. No limitations at all with down button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer for question 1:**

Yes, I faced the same problem in Google Chrome but I see no issues in Firefox(since FF does not update select value until user hits return). But I could not find the solution for the strange behavior when using keyboard in Chrome.

**Answer for question 2:**

For a better way to trigger the $resource call only when the user stops selecting an option from the drop-down, instead of using `ng-model-options`, try using `$timeout` and register a watcher on the model.

```
var timeout;
$scope.$watch('item', function (newVal) {
    if (newVal) {
        if (timeout) $timeout.cancel(timeout);
        timeout = $timeout(function () {
            // Resource call to service
            console.log("Changed!");
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/q5M84/1/)**

Comment: This seems like a more reliable solution. Much appreciated for your time.